# Why calling stored procedure in SQL server from x++ break AX?

Tags: sql-server, axapta

I have a script for renaming column in database written in X++.

```
public static server void renameColumn()
{
str sql;
Connection          oConnection;
Statement           oStatement;
ResultSet           resSet;
SqlStatementExecutePermission perm;

sql = strFmt( 'use DBNAME; exec sp_rename \'DBNAME.dbo.Table1.Name2\', \'Name1\', \'COLUMN\'');
oConnection = new Connection();
oStatement = oConnection.createStatement();
perm = new SqlStatementExecutePermission(sql);
perm.assert();
oStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

Which change existing column named **Name2** to **Name1**.

The strange errors start to occures few minutes later after I call it (using job).

```
Cannot select a record in Current AOS instances (SysServerSessions). ServerId: 0.
The SQL database has issued an error.
SQL error description: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'SYSSERVERSESSIONS'.
SQL statement: SELECT T1.SERVERID,T1.AOSID,T1.INSTANCE_NAME,T1.VERSION,T1.LOGINDATETIME,T1.LOGINDATETIMETZID,T1.STATUS,T1.LOADBALANCE,T1.WORKLOAD,T1.LASTUPDATEDATETIME,T1.LASTUPDATEDATETIMETZID,T1.AOSACCOUNT,T1.RECVERSION,T1.RECID,T2.SESSIONID,T2.SERVERID,T2.VERSION,T2.LOGINDATETIME,T2.LOGINDATETIMETZID,T2.STATUS,T2.USERID,T2.SID,T2.USERLANGUAGE,T2.HELPLANGUAGE,T2.CLIENTTYPE,T2.SESSIONTYPE,T2.CLIENTCOMPUTER,T2.DATAPARTITION,T2.RECVERSION,T2.RECID FROM SYSSERVERSESSIONS T1 CROSS JOIN SYSCLIENTSESSIONS T2 WHERE ((T2.SERVERID=T1.SERVERID) AND (T2.SESSIONID=?))

Cannot select a record in Alerts - event inbox (EventInbox).
The SQL database has issued an error.
SQL error description: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'EVENTINBOX'.
SQL statement: SELECT COUNT(T1.RECID) FROM EVENTINBOX T1 WHERE ((PARTITION=?) AND ((((ISREAD=?) AND (USERID=?)) AND (DELETED=?)) AND (VISIBLE=?)))
```

Anyone have an idea how to repair it and what exactly cause it?

Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3
Microsoft SQL Server 2012

P.S.: It can not be used without **use DBNAME;** because

```
SQL error description: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
```

Comment: It is possible that this kind of errors starts only if some information is wrong. Like attempt to rename field that do not exist.

Comment: Is the table where you want to rename a column part of the AX database (i.e. is the table part of the AOT)?

Comment: No it is in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: For one of our (SQL Server) integrations we used DSN/ODBC
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677510.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way that do not take AOS with it when crash. I am calling stored procedure without using

```
use DBNAME;
```

Instead of that I am using full name of stored procedure by

```
[DBNAME].[dbo].[sp_rename]
```

And when this crashed I get a normal SQL error:

```
Cannot execute the required database operation.
The SQL database has issued an error.
SQL error description: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]No item by the name of 'DBNAME.dbo.Table1.Name1' could be found in the current database 'DBNAME', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.
SQL statement: exec [VABO].[dbo].[sp_rename] 'DBNAME.dbo.Table1.Name1', 'Name2'
```

Axapta is using Microsoft SQL Server also so the

```
use DBNAME;
```

must break some inner settings.